# Dynamic SQL Error SQL Error COde =-104 Token Unknown - line 1, column 150

Tags: c#, firebird

```
FbConnection adder = new FbConnection(ClsConnection.FirebirdSQL);
            adder.Open();
            FbCommand fbcmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO 
 EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_NO,EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME,
 EMPLOYEE_FIRSTNAME,EMPLOYEE_MIDDLENAME,
 EMPLOYEE_BDATE,EMPLOYEE_STATUS,
 EMPLOYEE_POSITION) VALUES( 
 @textBox1.Text,@textBox2.Text,@textBox3.Text,
 @textBox4.Text,@textBox5.Text,@textBox6.Text,
 @textBox7.Text)", adder);
            // fbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            //FbCommand fbCom = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO players(ID,name,score) VALUES (@id,@name,@score)", fbCon);
            //fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", zID + 1);
            //fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", var);
            //fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("score", score);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox1", FbDbType.SmallInt);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox2", FbDbType.VarChar);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox3", FbDbType.VarChar);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox4", FbDbType.VarChar);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox5", FbDbType.VarChar);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox6", FbDbType.VarChar);
            fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox7", FbDbType.VarChar);

            fbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        fbcmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly, and ask an actual question in the body of your question and include the full error in the body (not just the title). BTW: Why are you tagging "mysql-error-10005" when you use Firebird.

Comment: After formatting is better visible :`@textBox1.Text,..Text,@textBox7.Text` are not params. Use textBox1.text(without `@`) ..... instead. Or use params as `@p1 = textBox1.Text`.

Comment: @ValMarinov Using without wouldn't work either (and if it would work that would lead to SQL injection)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If they are formatted properly (as strings for example) it will work. And yes, there will be conditions for a SQL Injection, but the question is  "Why this error arises ". So, I just point out the reason.I have also indicated that it can use parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three errors you made in morphing someone's example to your own needs.
Maybe there are more, but I am not C# guy and can not spot them.

**Error #1:** SQL terms do not include dots. And I think parameter identifiers can be classified as SQL terms.

Code from the Example you copy from:

> ....VALUES ( @id, @name, @score)"....

Code you made from this example:

> .....VALUES( @textBox1.Text,@textBox2.Text, .....

There is no dot in "`@name`" but suddenly there is dot in "`@textBox2.Text`"

**Error #2:** for SQL output-parameters it would be enough to only specify parameter data-type, as the value comes from the database. But for the input-parameters both data-type and the value are required. More so, often you can only provide value, as the database library would "infer" the data-type from the value. But the value MUST be provided for every input-parameter used.

Code from the Example you copy from:

> fbCom.Parameters.Add**WithValue**("name", **var**);

Code you made from this example:

> fbcmd.Parameters.Add("textBox2", FbDbType.VarChar);

There is the value binding in the example, but suddenly there is no any value in your code.

**Error #3:** When you use some named entity in programming, be it functions or variables or parameters, you typically refer them by the name, by the *identifier*. That means that in all places in your program that wants to use the same entity - the names should be exactly the same.

Code from the Example you copy from:

> ....VALUES ( @id, @**name**, @score)"....
>   fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("**name**", var);

Code you made from this example:

> .....VALUES( @textBox1.Text,@**textBox2.Text**, .....
>   fbcmd.Parameters.Add("**textBox2**", FbDbType.VarChar);

The source example code uses the SAME identifier in both lines - the "`name`" identifier. But you use DIFFERENT names: one line uses "`textBox2.Text'` identifier, but another line uses "`textBox2'` instead.

To make your code work as good as the example code is supposedly working you have to fix those three mistakes:

1. Fix the parameters names in your SQL, so they would be one-term names. Remove dots or other symbols not allowed in SQL terms from them parameter names.
2. Provide VALUES not only data-types for your parameters
3. When binding the values to the parameters, use exactly the same identifier that you put in your SQL.